# Missing `switchMap` and `flatMap` overloads containing 'resultSelector' in RxJS6

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I'm thoroughly confused about the new RxJS 6 and compatibility package. Currently I have these installed (for Angular 6):

```
"rxjs": "^6.1.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
```

I have been previously using [this signature](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) for `switchMap` (in RxJS5):

```
switchMap(
 project: function: Observable, 
 resultSelector: function(outerValue, innerValue, outerIndex, innerIndex): any): Observable
```

But when updating to version 6 only this overload is available (without the `resultSelector` parameter):

```
export declare function switchMap<T, R>(this: Observable<T>, 
       project: (value: T, index: number) => ObservableInput<R>): Observable<R>;
```

I'm importing it with

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

How can I get access to this overload?

Also I tried to look at `\node_modules\rxjs\operators\switchMap.d.ts` to see what signatures were in there but the contents of this file is :

```
 export * from 'rxjs-compat/operators/switchMap';
```

So it looks like the RxJS main package references the compatibility package? How does that make sense? Does the compatibility package actually modify RxJS - or has my package been corrupted - all the files show 1985 date stamps too!

Like I said I'm very confused! What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overload signatures for `switchMap` that include a result selector are available with v6 with or without `rxjs-compat` installed. It's just that those overloads are deprecated, as they will be removed in version 7.

In version 6, they can still be used; the deprecation is just a warning of an upcoming change.

From `rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.d.ts`:

```ts
import { ObservableInput, OperatorFunction } from '../types';
export declare function switchMap<T, R>(project: (value: T, index: number) => ObservableInput<R>): OperatorFunction<T, R>;
/** @deprecated resultSelector is no longer supported, use inner map instead */
export declare function switchMap<T, R>(project: (value: T, index: number) => ObservableInput<R>, resultSelector: undefined): OperatorFunction<T, R>;
/** @deprecated resultSelector is no longer supported, use inner map instead */
export declare function switchMap<T, I, R>(project: (value: T, index: number) => ObservableInput<I>, resultSelector: (outerValue: T, innerValue: I, outerIndex: number, innerIndex: number) => R): OperatorFunction<T, R>;
```

The purpose of `rxjs-compat` is not to change the `rxjs` installation, rather `rxjs` delegates to `rxjs-compat` for functionality that has been removed.

For example, when `rxjs-compat` is installed, v5-style imports will still work. That is, this will be fine with `rxjs-compat` installed:

```ts
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators/switchMap';
```

Whereas, without `rxjs-compat` installed, that import statement would effect an error.

For more information, see the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md).

Comment: I see in the migration guide it says 'deprecated' but it just literally isn't there for me. Won't compile - unless I remove the result selector function. (I see that they are removed for 'first', but should be there still for 'switchMap'). Still trying to figure out why.

Comment: (although with that said I actually want to remove all deprecated code so it's ok)

Comment: Something strange must be happening with your install or tooling. I have a bunch of minimal environments for checking things before I post answers and `switchMap` (with a result selector) works fine (when compiling and running) with `rxjs` + `rxjs-compat` v6.1.0 for me. Both with v6-style imports and v5-style imports.

Comment: Something to check: your tooling should be resolving `import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';` to `node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/index` via `rxjs/operators/index.d.ts`, etc. You mentioned `node_modules/rxjs/operators/switchMap.d.ts` - that should only be the target for v5-style imports like `import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators/switchMap`, etc.